# How can I calculate the checksum of code at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, checksum

I have a C#.NET application running on a machine. How do I calculate the checksum of the entire code at runtime?

#### Note:

I do not want to calculate the checksum of the image in use but the actual code part.

Comment: You'll need to be clearer. What do you mean by code -- C#/VB source, IL, machine code image, something else? And why would you want to checksum (couldn't you just use code signing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used this, but:

Using reflection you can navigate to the [GetILAsByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx) and do a checksum (per method).

But I think it will be a lot easier to use code signing or the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly and then do a checksum on the .dll or .exe.

Comment: you meant do a checksum of each and every method during runtime then group them together?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use [code signing](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/12/21/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought.aspx), but if you really want to roll your own solution (which may be a bad idea. Code signing is a Good Thing) you could use reflection to look into the IL code and calculate a checksum based on that. That's not a very nice solution, and could cause some weird bugs, so please, save yourself some trouble and use code signing.

Answer (score 1):

In runtime you don't have access to the original written source code.

Answer (score 0):

a strong name on your assembly does this - but you sort of have to trust that it is working as advertised. 
what is the precise problem you are tying to solve?

Comment: The problem is that they want a feature that does this. p_p