# Modules v. namespaces in F#

Tags: f#

I've got a library written in F#, consumed by C# and F#. this library defines a class `foo`, in module `bar`, in namespace `random`:

```
#light
namespace random

module bar

type foo() = ...
```

Now, when I go to consume type `random.foo.bar`, C# intellisense sees it as type `bar`, nested in type `random.foo`.

The question is this: Is there an advantage to C# to define externally-consumable code into modules, rather than namespaces? I understand that modules are a good way to group functions, but what about classes?

Comment: Possible dupe, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/795172/what-the-difference-between-a-namespace-and-a-module-in-f

Comment: sort of, but i was more looking for best practices for non-f# interop. that said, one is a corollary of the other.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're publishing F# components for consumption from other .Net languages, then you should avoid modules in the public interfaces, and stick to namespaces containing classes, structs, and enums.

(Modules are a handy way either to publish values, functions and types among F#-only components, or as 'internal' implementation details of an F# component that publishes .Net classes.)

(Do see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795172/what-the-difference-between-a-namespace-and-a-module-in-f) for a discussion of the 'technical distinction' between namespaces and modules.  This question and my answer above are more about the 'intentional differences' e.g. when you would choose to use each.)