# F#, namespaces, modules, fs and fsx

Tags: f#, namespaces, module, projects-and-solutions, f#-interactive

I'm aware of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155450/modules-v-namespaces-in-f) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172888/f-defining-and-using-a-namespace-in-the-same-project) about modules and namespaces in F#, but they're not helping me right now.

I've got a project with

**Utilities.fs**

```
namespace Company.Project.Namespace
module Utilities = 
     //stuff here
```

**Functions.fs**

```
namespace Company.Project.Namespace
open Utilities

module Functions = 
     //stuff here
```

And I'm trying to test them in an fsx:

```
#load "Utilities.fs"
#load "Functions.fs"
```

which gives me `error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Utilities' is not defined` when I try to send it to FSI with `Alt-Enter`.

I've tried adding same namespace at the top of the script file, but it doesn't like that.

What's weird is that the background compiler doesn't shout at me.

This seems to work, but is it the right approch?

```
#load "Utilities.fs"
open Company.Project.Namespace
#load "Functions.fs"
```

Is there a 'reference' FSharp project somewhere, which contains examples of how to integrate all this stuff: namespaces, modules, classes, script files, tests etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not an expert with FSI, but some experimentation suggests that namespaces are only supported by `#load` declarations (not via typical interactions - sending a namespace declaration group to VFSI via Alt-Enter does not work), and that different interactions contribute different 'instances'.  For example, with the code file

```
namespace Foo

type Bar() =
    member this.Qux() = printfn "hi"

namespace Other

type Whatever() = class end

namespace Foo

module M =
    let bar = new Bar()
    bar.Qux()
```

if I `#load` it more than once I get e.g.

```
> [Loading C:\Program.fs]
hi

namespace FSI_0002.Foo
  type Bar =
    class
      new : unit -> Bar
      member Qux : unit -> unit
    end
namespace FSI_0002.Other
  type Whatever =
    class
      new : unit -> Whatever
    end
namespace FSI_0002.Foo
  val bar : Bar

> #load @"C:\Program.fs";;
> [Loading C:\Program.fs]
hi

namespace FSI_0003.Foo
  type Bar =
    class
      new : unit -> Bar
      member Qux : unit -> unit
    end
namespace FSI_0003.Other
  type Whatever =
    class
      new : unit -> Whatever
    end
namespace FSI_0003.Foo
  val bar : Bar

> new Foo.Bar();;
> val it : Foo.Bar = FSI_0003.Foo.Bar
```

Note that it seems the FSI_0003.Foo.Bar shadowed the FSI_0002 version.

So I'm thinking the part of the F# spec that says

> Within a namespace declaration group,
>   the namespace itself is implicitly
>   opened if any preceding namespace
>   declaration groups or referenced
>   assemblies contribute to this
>   namespace, e.g.
>
> ```
> namespace MyCompany.MyLibrary 
>
>    module Values1 = 
>       let x = 1
>
> namespace MyCompany.MyLibrary 
>
>    // Implicit open of MyCompany.MyLibrary bringing Values1 into scope
>
>    module Values2 = 
>       let x = Values1.x
> ```
>
> However this only opens the namespace
>   as constituted by preceding namespace
>   declaration groups.

Does not interact with FSI, given FSI's limited understanding of namespaces.  Specifically, I expect that the 'second #load' from your example opens e.g. `FSI_000N+1`'s version of the namespace, whereas the prior code was in `FSI_000N`.  Which maybe-explains why the explicit `open` interaction fixes it; you bring the existing, unshadowed `FSI_000N` stuff up to the top level before trying to (implicitly) reference it later.

Comment: Yeah, as it happens, my question was a watered-down example of my actual code. I ended up getting it to work by re-opening the namespace between each #load...

Answer (score 8):

I'm relatively new at this too, but this is what works for me when I'm testing in an fsx file:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r @"C:\Program Files\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FParsec.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files\FSharpPowerPack-2.0.0.0\bin\FParsecCS.dll"
#endif

open FParsec.Primitives  
open FParsec.CharParsers
```

followed by my code that uses these libraries.