# Using ILMerge but retaining namespaces

Tags: .net, dll, ilmerge

Is it possible to merge a couple of assemblies via ILMerge and retain the initial namespaces of all libraries?

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Simply use ILMerge. It doesn't change any namespaces.
All it does is load the single [module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645728/what-is-a-module-in-net) from each assembly and put all the modules into one assembly.