# What is the "module" keyword in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, fody, .net-attributes

I am learning C# and came across the keyword `module`. I would like to know what this `module` keyword in C# is and how it is useful. For example, consider the below code:

```cs
[module: Test]
public class TestAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are viewing a unit test in C# and [module: Test] seems to state that the TestAttribute class is part of the Test module. 
I'm not a .NET developer, but from what I have read, a module seems to be a logical collection of code within an Assembly. 
The syntax may be part of the testing framework. Suggested reference links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645728/what-is-a-module-in-net; 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/unit-test-basics?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example `module` is a way to specify the attribute usage, like this:

```cs
[module: CLSCompliant(true)]
int Method1() { return 0; }
```

It is also called attribute *target*:

> The target of an attribute is the entity which the attribute applies to. For example, an attribute may apply to a class, a particular method, or an entire assembly. By default, an attribute applies to the element that follows it.

For the full list of C# attribute parameters check the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets).

Comment: Thank you, This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: Specifically, the `module` keyword when used this way applies an attribute to what the .NET Runtime calls a ["module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645728/what-is-a-module-in-net). In the vast, vast, vast majority of cases, each assembly has only one module, so most developers don't even know about modules.